# I'm looking to become an educator in mathematics, and am looking for resources for proof-based learning

Tags: education

As the title suggests, I intend to become a secondary mathematics educator, and I am looking for resources for teaching methods to introduce students to mathematical proofs, as well as for how to facilitate students reading and writing proofs.

If you know of any good texts, authors, or journal articles, please let me know!

Comment: This question better suits the [mathematics educators stack exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me there!